# MS-Tests: How to maintain test-setting across different dev-environments?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest

I am setting up a solution that is used by multiple developers/ teams that are working on different features of the next release of an application.

In my IntegrationTest-project I need to maintain the test-setting for the different teams. Basically each team uses a different test-server /web-services.

I can create a ".testsettings" file but I cannot find the section where I could define simple key-values pairs. For the testing I only need a few key-value pairs (server_url, webservice_url, ...)

Furthermore: How to I access the ".testsettings" at runtime form my unit-tests?